# How to enable math expressions in markdown mode?

Tags: markdown-mode

I have the following code saved as ex.md

```
---
title: "Page Title"
subtitle: "Page sub-title"
author: "Author name"
---

# head 1
hmm $x \times \pi$
```

and I preview with `C-c C-c p`, which opens the link in a browser. So, markdown does not recognize math mode. What do I need to enable it?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mV3xW_fJmI-S4vJB7VxsmR-rERM7ApGM/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: I discovered that for html I need to enable mathjax somehow. But how do I get a pdf? The preview and export commands immediately output html and do not ask a question what I want.

Answer (score 0):

In the browser, you need a markdown-viewer (search for a plugin for your browser). Alternatively, you could use [impatient-mode](https://melpa.org/#/impatient-showdown) (javascript, live-preview), [markdown-soma](https://melpa.org/#/markdown-soma) (rust, live-preview), grip-mode (python) or any other markdown preview mode available on Melpa (there are many).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48821981/how-to-convert-markdown-to-pdf-in-command-line) you can find various answers for how to convert markdown to pdf. You can use `M-!` to run these commands directly from Emacs, or configure the `markdown-command` as explained under 'Customization' [here](https://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/). For pandoc there is also [pandoc-mode](http://joostkremers.github.io/pandoc-mode/).

Comment: I do not have a problem when converting to pdf with pandoc. everything works. but I need to refer to mathjax somehow in my md file to make the html work. can you show me how?

Comment: From [here](https://pandoc.org/chunkedhtml-demo/3.6-math-rendering-in-html.html), it looks like you simply have to include the `--mathjax` argument in the command, as the default value for that argument (when using it without URL) is a link to the Cloudflare CDN. However, when I try it, it does not seem to insert the CDN in the html. In that case you can manually copy it from [here](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/stable/start.html) and insert it at the start of your html.